# Getting the child element id from parent and rendering the button in the id in parent component react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have one parent component and child component. I have to get the `id` from child in parent component and place button in the parent component using `ReactDom.render(somebutton, Id_of_the_child)`.

This one I have written in the component did update. But it's not working. Can anyone help me with this why this isn't working? Not able to get the child `id` in parent itself.

`Index.js`:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";

class parentComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
         super(props); 
    }

    onClick = () =>{
         console.log("some functionality is done")
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        if(document.getElementById("child_place_holder")){
             ReactDOM.render(< button onClick={this.onClick} 
        />,$("#child_place_holder")[0]);

        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
          <div>
             <ChildComponent/>
          </div>
        );
    }
}

export default parentComponent;
```

`ChildComponent.js`:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";

class ChildComponent extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
       super(props);  
   }

   componentDidMount(){}
  
   render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <span id = "child_place_holder"> </span>
        </div>    
      );
   }
}
```

Comment: Please share a [mcve] of what you’re doing. It’s likely what you want can be done in a different way

Comment: I concur with @evolutionxbox. There isn't usually much reason to work with an element's `id` if you're inside of React, as you can generally use a reference made within scope. Posting an example will help considerably here.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I have one index file where I have to write button functionality which I had done. So same thing need to be done in child component instead of writing it there I just want that button to be displayed in child component so I want to get id of that place in child where button should be displayed.

Comment: Whilst your description is helpful, a [mcve] would be much much more useful.

Comment: I did not get you actually @evolutionxbox

Comment: We can't help with code we cannot see. Please read the article I have linked?

Comment: Please check I have added the sample code @evolutionxbox